# PowerShell script to check the name format of all folders in a directory and create subfolders in each one

Tags: powershell, regex, rename

I have a Main folder which contains many folders with the name format: capital letter and four numbers (A4431). The script in PowerShell I am trying to write needs to go through all the folders in my Main folder and check, if they have the correct name format and change it if it is not the correct one. After that it needs to create a subfolder structure in each folder in my main folder. The subfolder structure consists of 4 folders, one of which has its own subfolders. The names of the subfolder structure is always the same. The end result should look like this:

```
Main Folder
 **-A4431**
  -Customers
  -Supplier
  -Orders
    -Sub Folder1
    -Sub Folder2
  -Items
 **-C1131**
  -Customers
  -Supplier
  -Orders
    -Sub Folder1
    -Sub Folder2
  -Items
...
```

This is what I have done so far, but it does not do much. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
#Main directory 
$root = "C:\Work files\Test\Main folder"

#Folder name example (A3234)
$pattern = "^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}"

#Subfolder structure needed to be created in each folder
$folders_names = "Customers","Supplier","Orders","Items"

#Get all folders in $root
$dirs = Get-ChildItem $root | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}

#loop through all folders in root and check if they have the right name format and change it if necessary
ForEach ($dir in $dirs)
{
    if(!$dir -match $pattern){
        $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}') 
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Force 
    }
    #create subfolders in each folder in $root
    ForEach ($name in $folder_names){
        New-item -path "$root\$dir" -Name $name -Type 'directory'
    }
}
```

**EDIT AFTER YOUR SUGGESTIONS**

This is the current state of the problem. I am trying to generate a random folder name, that I will use to replace the folder name for each folder that does not match the pattern.

```
$regex = "^([A-Z]){1}\d{4}"
$randomNr = Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 9999
$randomLetter = @("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P")

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.BaseName -notmatch '^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}')
    {"The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is not valid. Changing folder name"
      $newName = $randomLetter + $randomNr
      Rename-Item $PSItem.BaseName -NewName $newName.ToString() -WhatIf
    }
    
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Renaming object: Renaming is not possible because the element does not exist under "v77".
In line: 10 characters: 7
+ Rename item $ PSItem.BaseName -NewName $ newName.ToString () -Was ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId: InvalidOperation, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

The folder structure inside my MainFolder looks as follows. Folder v77 is the one that is sopposed to be renamed to match the pattern C####. Any ideas on how this could be done properly. I am really thankful for the answers so far!
[Test folder structure inside MainFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmnZt.jpg)

Comment: Post on StackOverflow instead of here, with the same tags. Theres an operator for -notmatch as well so skip the alias for `-not / !`.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post just leads to us having to make assumptions.

As a rule, to limit/eliminate confusion, break your use case into steps and perform them one at a time to ensure you are getting what you'd expect, prior to moving to the next.

*** Step 1 - Read the directory tree and validate folder names ***

What if your tree was this:

[image: DummyFolderTree]

```
Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.BaseName -match '^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}')
    {"The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is valid. Processing folder tree"}
    Else {Write-Warning -Message "The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is not valid. Updating folder tree."}
}
# Results
<#
WARNING: The folder named 56U87 is not valid. Updating folder tree.
WARNING: The folder named 9999d is not valid. Updating folder tree.
The folder A4431 is named valid. Processing folder tree
The folder B1234 is named valid. Processing folder tree
The folder C1131 is named valid. Processing folder tree
WARNING: The folder Test is not valid. Updating folder tree.
#>
```

So, as you can see, your very first step is questionable. As, you are saying all folder names are to be a specific construct, and if they are not, then change them. ***Change them to what?*** If they don't meet the taxonomy, how would you know what they are and what to change them to, so that they are not duplicates of those which already exist?

How would consider fixing that 'Test' folder or the others?  You'd end up having to look at all folders, to get all names and make a decision on what to name it to avoid name collisions.

If you are saying that all folder names will be this...

```
'^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}'
```

... then that also means parsing the string that does not match and move stuff around, uppercase things, or completely rename.

So, until you solidify that, the rest is moot.

*** Step 2 Create child folders ***

```
Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.BaseName -match '^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}' )
    {
        $ParentFolder = $PSItem.FullName
        "The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is valid. Processing folder tree"
        'Customers','Supplier','Orders','Items' | 
        ForEach {New-Item -Path $ParentFolder -Name $PSItem -ItemType Directory -WhatIf}
    }
    Else {Write-Warning -Message "The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is not valid. Updating folder tree."}
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' -Recurse
# Results
<#
WARNING: The folder named 56U87 is not valid. Updating folder tree.
WARNING: The folder named 9999d is not valid. Updating folder tree.
The folder named A4431 is valid. Processing folder tree
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Customers".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Supplier".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Orders".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Items".
The folder named B1234 is valid. Processing folder tree
...
#>
```

*** Step 3 Create Grandchild folders only for the child folder Orders ***

```
Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.BaseName -match '^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}' )
    {
        $ParentFolder = $PSItem.FullName
        "The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is valid. Processing folder tree"
        'Customers','Supplier','Orders','Items' | 
        ForEach {
            New-Item -Path $ParentFolder -Name $PSItem -ItemType Directory -WhatIf

            $GrandChildFolder = "$ParentFolder\$PSItem"
        
            If ($GrandChildFolder -match 'Orders')
            {
                1..2 | 
                ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path $GrandChildFolder  -Name "Folder$PSItem" -ItemType Directory -WhatIf}
            }
        }
    }
    Else {Write-Warning -Message "The folder named $($PSItem.BaseName) is not valid. Updating folder tree."}
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' -Recurse
# Results
<#
WARNING: The folder named 56U87 is not valid. Updating folder tree.
WARNING: The folder named 9999d is not valid. Updating folder tree.
The folder named A4431 is valid. Processing folder tree
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Customers".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Supplier".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Orders".
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Orders\Folder1".
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Orders\Folder2".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431\Items".
The folder named B1234 is valid. Processing folder tree
...
WARNING: The folder named Test is not valid. Updating folder tree.
#>
```

***Update - as per my last comment***

If you are absolutely sure that the taxonomy is always `C####`. then just do a bulk rename can call it a day.

```
Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder'
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/19/2021   2:59 PM                A4431
d-----         5/19/2021   3:00 PM                B1234
d-----         5/19/2021   3:00 PM                C1131
d-----         5/19/2021   3:00 PM                d9999
d-----         5/19/2021   3:02 PM                u5687
#>

Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' -Directory | 
Rename-Item -NewName {($TempName = "_$($PSItem.BaseName.ToUpper())")}

Get-ChildItem 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' -Directory | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$PSItem.BaseName -replace '_',''}


Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder'
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/19/2021   2:59 PM                A4431
d-----         5/19/2021   3:00 PM                B1234
d-----         5/19/2021   3:00 PM                C1131
d-----         5/19/2021   3:00 PM                D9999
d-----         5/19/2021   3:02 PM                U5687
#>
```

The remaining code is the same.

```
Clear-Host

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' | 
ForEach-Object {
    $ParentFolder = $PSItem.FullName

    'Customers','Supplier','Orders','Items' | 
    ForEach {
        New-Item -Path $ParentFolder -Name $PSItem -ItemType Directory

        $GrandChildFolder = "$ParentFolder\$PSItem"
       
        If ($PSItem -match 'Orders')
        {
            1..2 | 
            ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path $GrandChildFolder  -Name "Folder$PSItem" -ItemType Directory}
        }
    }
}
```

***Update - as per our follow-up comments***

Here is an idea of what I am trying to provide edification on. Note this is just one way. As we all know, PowerShell has a number of ways to accomplish X or Y, with some approaches more elegant than others. The below is a but still rough around the edges, but does make changes. So, you'll need to tweak it for your use case.

```
Clear-Host
$Increment = 1

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' -Directory | 
ForEach-Object{
    $FolderName       = $PSItem
    $FolderNameLength = $PSItem.BaseName.Length

    switch ($FolderNameLength)
    {
        5        
        {
            $FolderName | 
            Rename-Item -NewName $($FolderName.Name).ToUpper() -WhatIf
        }
        Default  
        {
            If ($FolderName.Name.Length -lt 5)
            {
                If(-Not (Test-Path -Path "$($folderName.Parent.FullName)\$($($FolderName.Name).PadRight(5, '0').ToUpper())))"))
                {Rename-Item -Path $FolderName.FullName -NewName $($FolderName.Name).PadRight(5, '0').ToUpper() -WhatIf}
            }
            Else
            {
                If((Test-Path -Path "$($folderName.Parent.FullName)\$($($FolderName.Name.Substring(0,5).ToUpper())))"))
                {$FolderName.Name.Substring(0,5).ToUpper()}
                Else {Rename-Item -Path $FolderName.FullName -NewName ($FolderName.Name.Substring(0,5).ToUpper() -replace $FolderName.Name.Substring(1,4), ([string][int]$FolderName.Name.Substring(1,3) + ($Increment++))) -WhatIf}
            }
        }
    }
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\B1234 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\B1234".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\C1131 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\C1131".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\d9999 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\D9999".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\u5687 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\U5687".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\v77 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\V7700".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\v778 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\V7780".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X10000 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X1001".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\x100000 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X1002".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\z123456789 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\Z1233".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\z1234567890 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\Z1234".
#>
```

***Here is a refactor to deal with a use case in the above:***

Remember only run code you get from others in a test environment or leverage `-WhatIf and or -Confirm`

```
Clear-Host

$WhatIfPreference      = $true
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$SourcePath            = 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder'
$Increment             = 1

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath  -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.BaseName.Length -eq 5)
    {
        $TempName = ($PSItem     | 
        Rename-Item -NewName {("_$($PSItem.BaseName.ToUpper())")} -PassThru)

        Get-Item -Path $TempName | 
        Rename-Item -NewName {$PSItem.FullName -replace '_',''}    
    }


    If ($PSItem.BaseName.Length -lt 5)
    {Rename-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -NewName $($PSItem.BaseName).PadRight(5,'0').ToUpper()}


    If ($PSItem.BaseName.Length -gt 5)
    {
        Rename-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -NewName $(
            $(($PSItem.BaseName.Substring(0,5)).ToUpper()) -replace 
            '\d{4}', ($($PSItem.BaseName.Substring(1,3) + $Increment++))
        )
    }
}

$WhatIfPreference      = $false
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
```

***Update ---
or a random rename refactor for all of them to enforce your taxonomy, regardless of the original name***

```
Clear-Host

$WhatIfPreference      = $true
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$Increment = 1

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder' -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    $NewFolderName = (([char[]](65..90))  | Get-Random -Count 1) + 
                     (([char[]]((48..57)) | Get-Random -Count 4) -join '')

    If ($PSItem.BaseName -cnotmatch ($PSItem.BaseName.ToUpper()))
    {Rename-Item $PSItem.FullName -NewName ($PSItem.BaseName -creplace $PSItem.BaseName, $NewFolderName)}
    Else
    {
        Rename-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -NewName $(
            $(($PSItem.BaseName.Substring(0,5)).ToUpper()) -replace 
            '\d{4}', ($($NewFolderName.Substring(1,3) + $Increment++))
        )    
    }
}

$WhatIfPreference      = $false
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A4431 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\A6121".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\B1234 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\B5102".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\C1131 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\C5233".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\d9999 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X7184".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\u5687 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\C4251".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\v77 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\B6340".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\v778 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\P1738".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X10000 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X3764".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\x100000 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\D1845".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\x100003 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\G5641".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X100004 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\X9685".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\z123456789 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\S7638".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\Z1234567890 Destination: C:\WorkFiles\Test\MainFolder\Z6916".
#>
```

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear. So for the first step, the pattern for all the folders in the Main folder always has to be one capital letter followed by four numbers. So if any of the folders do not match this format they need to be renamed to match the format - B3224 for example. But you are completely correct when you say that name duplication also must be avoided. The question is how to do that in the first step, so that after step 1 runs through all folders will have the correct name format and then step 2,3 can create the subfolders?

Comment: No worries. Yet, as for this `So for the first step, the pattern for all the folders in the Main folder always has to be one capital letter followed by four numbers.`, are you saying that no matter what, that folder will only have that pattern, but the 1 char could be upper or lower? You do know that in Windows, there is no case sensitivity for file and folder names. Setting them one way or the other is just cosmetic. Hence you looking for `[a-zA-Z]` is really moot as well, that just RegEx. So, if all things must be uppercase, then just do that as the default, all else remains the same.

Comment: I think what you are suggesting won't work because, if a folder has a name like v77 it needs to be renamed to match the pattern of letter and four numbers. I have been trying to generate a random name that matches C#### and replace the folder name with the random name, but I get the following error:

`Renaming object: Renaming is not possible because the element does not exist under "v77".
In line: 10 characters: 7
+ Rename item $ PSItem.BaseName -NewName $ newName.ToString () -Was ...`

v77 is the test folder in the Main folder directory that I want to change in C#### format.

Comment: Hi @postanote I have edited my post with what I last did, so it is more clear to understand. Do you have any further advice?

Comment: The error you are encountering is expected based on your use case, which is why we asked for real data in your use case. Your response seems to say that the folder will always be a single character followed by 1-4 or more numbers, and you want to limit it to 1+4 only. Thus this means you must scan for length, and string, and pad/auto-incremented or drop digits and ensure there are no duplicates. Correct me if I am mistaken? If I am not, then there is way more to this effort that needs to be considered, relative to the thought process I just stated.

Comment: You are not mistaken this is exactly what I want to do. The folders need to be a single character followed by 4 numbers. If I have a folder that is different to this format it needs to be renamed.  "Thus this means you must scan for length, and string, and pad/auto-incremented or drop digits and ensure there are no duplicates." - the problem is I have no idea how to implement this. Is there any chance you can help me further with it. I am really out of my depth here.

Comment: OK, then building comparison logic via a  [try/catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement#:~:text=Parts%20%20%20%20Term%20%20%20,class%20fi%20...%20%207%20more%20rows%20) would give you the logic to accomplish this. Read folder names where length is less than 5, more than 5, or equal to 5, then validate/process art each catch block or using if/then or a switch statement. You know, conditional logic stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer and explanations. Thanks to your help I was able to do what I wanted in the end!

Comment: No worries. Good to know it got you to where you wanted to be.